# Javascript while loop innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

Very new to Javascript.

Having trouble displaying result of while loop to html page. I am trying to use document.getElementById, but i think i am using it incorrectly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
function day() {
    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getDate();

    var counter = 0;

    while (counter < today) {
        document.write("Hello ");
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    console.log(today);
}
```

My HTML is here where i am calling day

```
<button type="button" onclick="day()">Run Loop</button>
<p id="date4"></p>
```

Comment: I don't see getElementById in your sample code. Where are you using it?

Comment: Well your while loop will be running really long. Using document.write is a bad idea. You do not show how you call `day`.

Comment: Leo I added in the getElementById in the code

Comment: Calling *document.write* after the load event will cause the **entire** content of the document to be removed and replaced with the string passed to the call.

Comment: What were you trying to do exactly? Were you trying to show a counter on the document?

Answer (score 0):

I will change

```
document.write("Hello");
```

//  after the document loads document.write will overwrite the document.

for

```
document.getElementById("date4").innerHTML = "Hello";
```

Comment: I tried this, but it just printed hello once when the function was called. Is there a way to display result of the function?

Comment: Yes I just corrected the example that you gave using hello. If you want to display the counter just replace "Hello" with your counter variable. 
      `document.getElementById("date4").innerHTML = counter;`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (Assuming you are loading jQuery)

```
function day() {
    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getDate();
    var counter = 0;

    while (counter < today) {
        counter = counter + 1;
         $("#date4").html(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not using jquery, is there another way to do it, using javascript?